# Custom Altium footpring

Tags: altium, footprint

[image: Footprint]

I want to design a concentric circle shaped footprint in Altium. The inner one is Vcc while the outer is GND. I tried placing the pad and such but there is no way I can have the outer circle with the clearance as shown.

One way is to place an arc (that is complete). But then how can I assign a designator (pin 1,2) to it ?

Comment: You will probably need to associate it with a schematic component.

Comment: I have a schematic symbol ready. The schematic has 2 pins/ports 1 and 2. When it comes to footprint we can associate designators only to PADS. Thats where I am stuck. I am unable to make the ground pad. This shape can be designed using an arc but then arcs cannot be assigned a designator.

Comment: Have you tried placing a small SMT pad on the outer concentric circle of copper?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany That is exactly what needs to be done.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany. Thank you for your response. WHen I place an SMT it will be a circle. Is there any way I can define a rule that will ensure that the area covered by the inner circle is removed ?

Answer (score 0):

You should create your shape :
1) using "Arc" create a half ring
2) convert it to "Region"
3) then copy and mirror it and stick two half rings to create a complete ring
4) place some Pads(with same designator) into ring region for connecting tracks(i prefer that these pad hidden in my custom region)

5)for your central part just use normal pad.

[image]