# Altium Multiple ring-shaped pad

Tags: altium

I want to create custom pad with several rings shape pad in Altium.

I already create the region for each ring but unable to convert ring 3 and 4 to a pad (each is half ring x 2). As you can see on below image ring one and two is a pad but rings three and four have mask on it.

[image]
[image]

When I click to convert the ring two and three to pad, I get below error. (But it works on ring two).

[image: .]

I have followed this [link][4] to create rings.
Could you please let me know what I am doing wrong.

[Custom Altium footpring](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/495341/custom-altium-footpring)

Answer (score 1):

Essentially the error comes from the fact that the center of the polygon (which is where the connection should be made) is not part of your pad. By making several smaller piece, it might work.

An other way to do it (the way I  usually solve those issue) is to create a pad and placing it on the polygon. You will need a polygon for copper and one for solder mask (and maybe one for solder paste). Then, you can make a rule exception for it in the DRC and it should work fine.

A third way to do it is if you are using Altium 2023, they introduced custom shaped pads. This could probably work too but it might not do as clean of a circle.

Finally the Altium forum might have a solution that I didn't thought of.

Comment: I don't use custom pad tools myself, but if the centroid is what matters, it might work to construct a concave polygon with a zero-width connection to the interior, like this but with the gap closed to zero: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJWX1.png